# Is there a way to determine which functions are invoked from a go module during compilation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, go-modules

I am writing a number AWS Lambda functions using Go.  Common functionality is divided into modules, for example I have a module (M1) that provides an implementation of an interface with a backing store in terms of DynamoDB (so has a dependency on AWS Go SDK).

In one Lambda function (F1) I import M1, so the dependency graph for a code path looks like this:

```
F1 -> M1 -> SDK -> dynamodb.DynamoDB.PutItem
```

Being AWS I need to write a corresponding IAM policy to permit F1 to execute `PutItem`.

At the moment I identify the AWS SDK calls by hand and fix any errors that are loggged in CloudWatch.

My goal is to determine whether there is a way to get the Go toolchain to identify which functions are invoked from a given module/import.

So far I can tried a few variations of the below:

```
# this doesn't return much as most of my code lives within directories
# under main
go mod why "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go"
# github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
(main module does not need package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go)

# this only identifies a single F1 {-> ...} -> SDK invocation
# but not all of them
grep -r github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go --include="*.go" \
  | cut -f2 -d'"' \
  | sort -u \
  | xargs go mod why
```

I've not dipped into the source of `go build` and `go mod why`, but so far I can't see a way to convince "go mod why" to understand simple glob expansions/regex and the corresponding invocation points.  I also haven't made any headway on the second order deps (i.e. M1->SDK).

Answer (score 1):

`go mod graph` will give you your dependency graph, but that won't tell you what functions are being called; that's not in the scope of dependency management, which operates at the module level. To see what functions are being called you'd need to either parse the source via [AST](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/), or instrument the binary with e.g. [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/).

Comment: Thanks, `go mod graph` served as a great starting point.  Annoyingly the packages that it uses are all internal and inaccessible programmatically.  Led me to `golang.org/x/tools/go/packages` and seeing a lot of potential with `packages.Load(&packages.Config{Mode:packages.LoadTypes}, "...")`

Comment: Internals can't be imported but they're still accessible for parsing/grepping/pprof - basically any mechanism you could use to analyse function calls.